# nested iif expression within a matrix in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, nested, expression, iif

I have a report in SSRS using matrix format that contains alternate color rows using `=IIF(VAL(ReportItems!ROWCOLOR.Value) MOD 2,"Gainsboro","White")`.

The report contains data based on "Metric IDs" and what I'm trying to achieve is a conditional formatting based on values that will highlight certain metrics performances.  I only want to target specific Metric IDs and the rest of the data leave it as alternating color rows as mentioned above.

Here is how I wrote my expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value = "87" AND Fields!METRIC_VALUE_VOLUME.Value < 28 , "Green", 
 IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value = "87" AND Fields!METRIC_VALUE_VOLUME.Value < 30 , "Yellow", 
 IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value = "87" AND Fields!METRIC_VALUE_VOLUME.Value > 30 , "Red" ,
IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value <> "87"AND VAL(ReportItems!ROWCOLOR.Value) MOD 2,"Gainsboro","White"))))
 
AND
 
IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value = "25" AND Fields!METRIC_VALUE_VOLUME.Value < 28 , "Green", 
 IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value = "25" AND Fields!METRIC_VALUE_VOLUME.Value < 30 , "Yellow", 
 IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value = "25" AND Fields!METRIC_VALUE_VOLUME.Value > 30 , "Red" ,
IIF(Fields!METRIC_ID.Value <> "25"AND VAL(ReportItems!ROWCOLOR.Value) MOD 2,"Gainsboro","White"))))
```

The expression works only if I use one Metric ID; when I use a second ID as written above my output report with alternating colors do not work and the colors in my expression do not appear either.  Is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: Have you looked at using Switch instead? It can make this a little easier to write, not to mention read.

Comment: Textbox references such as `VAL(ReportItems!ROWCOLOR.Value)` are not particularly reliable. Have you looked into the `RowNumber` function?